# Fillna with backwards and forward looking condition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I am working with a dataframe that has a column with several NaN that I want to fill according to the following condition:
If going backwards and forward up to 3 rows there are 2 equal values, then fill the NaN with that value.

Since this might not be clear, a couple of examples below:

```
  col1                    
0 10    
1 10  
2 NaN
3 NaN
4 NaN
5 10
6 5
7 NaN
8 5
9 NaN
10 NaN
11 NaN
12 NaN
```

- The value in row 2 has a 10 at 1 row going back and a 10 in 3 rows going forward. --> Fill with 10
- The value in row 3 has a 10 at 2 rows going back and a 10 in 2 rows going forward. --> Fill with 10
- The value in row 4 has a 10 at 3 rows going back and a 10 in 1 row going forward. --> Fill with 10
- The value in row 7 has a 5 at 1 row going back and a 5 in 1 row going forward. --> Fill with 5
- The value in row 9 has a 5 at 1 row going back but no 5 in the 3 rows going forward. --> Then, don't fill

Then, the result would be like this:

```
  col1                    
0 10    
1 10  
2 10
3 10
4 10
5 10
6 5
7 5
8 5
9 NaN
10 NaN
11 NaN
12 NaN
```

Is there any functionality I can use to give this logic to the `fillna`?

Thanks!!

Comment: The documentation of [`fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) states that the method only support `ffill` or `backfill` (also referred to as `pad` and `bfill`, respectively). You will have to implement a function to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compare forward filling and back filling `Series` with limit parameter, chain mask with `&` for bitwise AND for only rows with missing values and replace it by forward filling column:

```
m1 = df['col1'].isna()
f = df['col1'].ffill(limit=3)
m2 = f.eq(df['col1'].bfill(limit=3))

df['col2'] = df['col1'].mask(m1 & m2, f)
print (df)
    col1  col2
0   10.0  10.0
1   10.0  10.0
2    NaN  10.0
3    NaN  10.0
4    NaN  10.0
5   10.0  10.0
6    5.0   5.0
7    NaN   5.0
8    5.0   5.0
9    NaN   NaN
10   NaN   NaN
11   NaN   NaN
12   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! I didn't know the `mask()` function. Thanks.